# Slow loading of large NumPy datasets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ordereddictionary

I notice a long loading time (~10 min) of a .npy file for a 1D numpy array of object data type and with a length of ~10000. Each element in this array is an ordered dictionary (OrderedDict, a dictionary subclass from collections package) with a length ~5000. So, how can I efficiently save and load large NumPy arrays to and from disk? How are large data sets in Python traditionally handled?

Comment: For a numeric array of that size the load should be quite fast.   It just writes/reads the databuffer without much processing.  But with objects, you are limited by the pickling speed of those objects.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy will pickle embedded objects by default (which you could avoid with `allow_pickle=False` but sounds like you may need it) which is slow (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).
You may want to check Pandas (see http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization) or try to come up with your own file format that avoids pickling of your complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Saving and loading large datasets to/from disk will always be a costly operation. One possible optimization is using memory mapping to disk and working directly on the array (if this is compatible with your application), especially if you're only interested in a small part of the dataset. This is what numpy.memmap does.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.memmap('largeArray.dat',dtype=np.int32,mode='w+',shape=(100000,))
```

this will create a numpy array 'a' of 1000000 int32. It can be handled as any "normal" numpy array. This also creates the corresponding file 'largeArray' on your disk that will contain the data in 'a'. Synchronization between 'a' and 'largeArray' is handled by numpy and this depends on your RAM size.

More info [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)